# using globals() with class method in python

Tags: python, function, class, methods, global

```
class MyModules:
   def Play_Music(self):
     print(123)

function_name = 'Play_Music'
```

this is a simplified code. I need to call this function with a **globals()** function, like **globals()[function_name]**. but it is inside a class, so it is not global function, so i cannot use it in this way. How can i do this, i tried **globals()[MyModules+function_name]()** or **globals()['MyModules.'+function_name]()**, and it did not work. help me pleease

Comment: What is wrong with writing `MyModules.Play_Music`? Also `Play_Music` should probably be called on an instance of your `MyModules` class. Which instance do you want to call it on? I think you need to show a bit more context.

Comment: "I need to call this function with a globals() function…" Why? This seems like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You are asking for a specific technique that presumably solves some problem. If you describe the problem, there's probably a much more pythonic way to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running this code in a global scope:

```
objMyModules = MyModules()
Play_Music = objMyModules.Play_Music
```

will put Play_Music into global scope with the appropriate function behind it, so that `globals()[function_name]` will give you the requested result:

```
class MyModules:
   def Play_Music(self):
     print(123)

function_name = 'Play_Music'

objMyModules = MyModules()
Play_Music = objMyModules.Play_Music

globals()[function_name]() # prints 123
```